# Ingress NGINX client closed connection while SSL handshaking

Tags: ssl, nginx, nginx-ingress

we have ingress-nginx running for a while and about 10% of requests ending up with some SSL handshake problem.

Here is an example of a failing connection:

```
2019/02/14 10:15:35 [debug] 237#237: *4612 accept: **.**.**.**:40928 fd:53
2019/02/14 10:15:35 [debug] 237#237: *4612 event timer add: 53: 60000:5527050245
2019/02/14 10:15:35 [debug] 237#237: *4612 reusable connection: 1
2019/02/14 10:15:35 [debug] 237#237: *4612 epoll add event: fd:53 op:1 ev:80002001
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 http check ssl handshake
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 http recv(): 0
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [info] 237#237: *4612 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: **.**.**.**, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 close http connection: 53
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 event timer del: 53: 5527050245
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 reusable connection: 0
2019/02/14 10:15:45 [debug] 237#237: *4612 free: 00007F4CC5858E00, unused: 232
```

10% of failures seems to be quite a lot to expect.

I really would appreciate any help in this!

Comment: Your question at this stage is offtopic here since not related to programming (until maybe you find out your problems come from a specific program). For now you will be better ontopic on [sf] for example. But you are not providing a lot of data... Do you control the server ? The client ? What are your TLS settings ? And nginx/OS versions ? etc.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. We'll post it at Server Fault.